# Item not iterable when adding to state in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, state

I am currently trying to push items into an array in React using the spread operator, however am getting the following error.

[image: error]

The error occurs in the PhotoUploader component inside the PlacesForm.jsx. I've included the code up to the component below.

PlacesForm.jsx:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import AccountNav from './AccountNav'
import Perks from './Perks'
import PhotosUploader from './PhotosUploader'

function PlacesForm() {
    const {id} = useParams()

    const [title, setTitle] = useState("")
    const [address, setAddress] = useState("")
    const [addedPhotos, setAddedPhotos] = useState([]) //state in question
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("")
    const [perks, setPerks] = useState([])
    const [extraInfo, setExtraInfo] = useState("")
    const [checkIn, setCheckIn] = useState("")
    const [checkOut, setCheckOut] = useState("")
    const [maxGuests, setMaxGuests] = useState(1)


    useEffect(() => {
        if (!id) return 
        const getPlace = async () => {
            try {
                const {data} = await axios.get(`/places/${id}`)
                setTitle(data.title)
                setAddress(data.address)
                setAddedPhotos(data.addedPhotos)
                setDescription(data.description)
                setPerks(data.perks)
                setExtraInfo(data.extraInfo)
                setCheckIn(data.checkIn)
                setCheckOut(data.checkOut)
                setMaxGuests(data.maxGuests)
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        }
        getPlace()
    }, [id])

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const inputHeader = (text) => {
        return (
            <h2 className='text-2xl mt-4'>{text}</h2>
        )
    }

    const inputDescription = (text) => {
        return (
            <p className="text-gray-500 text-sm">{text}</p>
        )
    }

    const preInput = (header, description) => {
        return (
            <>
                {inputHeader(header)}
                {inputDescription(description)}
            </>
        )
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const placeData = {
            title,
            address, 
            addedPhotos, 
            description,
            perks,
            extraInfo,
            checkIn,
            checkOut,
            maxGuests
        }
        if (id) {
            //update 
            try {
                const res = await axios.put('/places', {
                    id,
                    ...placeData,
                })
                navigate('/account/places')
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        } else {
            //create new place 
            try {
                const res = await axios.post('/places', placeData)
                navigate('/account/places')
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }

    }

  return (
    <>
        <div>
            <AccountNav />  
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                {preInput('Title', 'Something catchy and memorable')} 
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="title" 
                    value={title} 
                    onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} 
                />

                {preInput('Address', 'be specific')} 
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="address" 
                    value={address}
                    onChange={e => setAddress(e.target.value)}
                />

                
                {preInput('Photos', 'Best to have at least 4')}
                <PhotosUploader addedPhotos={addedPhotos} setAddedPhotos={setAddedPhotos} />
```

The error occurs in both the addPhotobyLink() and uploadPhoto() functions. The post requests and backend work fine and 'filename' is defined for both, however, something goes wrong in the 'setAddedPhotos' part.  Here is the component itself (PhotoUploader.jsx):

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function PhotosUploader({addedPhotos, setAddedPhotos}) {
    const [photoLink, setPhotoLink] = useState("")
    

    const addPhotoByLink = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            const {data:filename} = await axios.post('/upload-by-link', {link: photoLink})
            setAddedPhotos(prev => [...prev, filename])

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        setPhotoLink("")
    }

    const uploadPhoto = async (e) => {
        const files = e.target.files
        const data = new FormData()
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            data.append('photos', files[i])
        }
        try {
            const {data:filenames} = await axios.post('/upload', data, {
                headers: {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
            })
            setAddedPhotos(prev => [...prev, ...filenames])
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

  return (
    <>
        <div className='flex gap-2' >
            <input 
                value={photoLink} 
                onChange={e => setPhotoLink(e.target.value)} 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Add using link ....jpg" 
            />
            <button 
                onClick={addPhotoByLink} 
                className='bg-gray-200 px-4 rounded-2xl'
            >
                Add&nbsp;photo
            </button>
        </div>                    

        <div className="grid gap-2 grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-6 md:grid-cols-4 mt-2">
            {addedPhotos?.length > 0 && addedPhotos.map((link) => (
                <div key={link} className="h-32 flex">
                    <img 
                        src={'http://localhost:3000/uploads/' + link} 
                        alt=""
                        className='rounded-2xl w-full object-cover position' 
                    />
                </div>
            ))}
            <label className="h-32 cursor-pointer flex items-center justify-center gap-2 border bg-transparent rounded-2xl p-2 text-2xl text-gray-600">
                <input type="file" multiple className='hidden' onChange={uploadPhoto}/>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" className="w-8 h-8">
                    <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M3 16.5v2.25A2.25 2.25 0 005.25 21h13.5A2.25 2.25 0 0021 18.75V16.5m-13.5-9L12 3m0 0l4.5 4.5M12 3v13.5" />
                </svg>
                Upload
            </label>
        </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default PhotosUploader
```

So far, I've tried:

```
setAddedPhotos(prev => [...prev, filename]) //didn't work
setAddedPhotos([...prev, filename]) //didn't work
setAddedPhotos([...addedPhotos, filename]) //didn't work, addPhotos isn't iterable error
setAddedPhotos(prev => [...addedPhotos, filename]) //didn't work
```

Comment: `addedPhotos` doesn't contain an array. Probably the data coming in in the first file's useEffect doesn't have any photo data. `setAddedPhotos(prev => { console.log("Previous value:", prev); return [...prev, ...filenames]; })` to confirm.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I was able to fix it. You were right in that the useEffect doesn't get the photo data. the object key was called 'photos' not 'addedphotos', which was why it was undefined. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**In React, it is generally not recommended to pass down a state updater function**

One reason for this is that it can lead to unnecessary re-renders and make the code harder to reason about. If a child component receives the setAddedPhotos function as a prop and calls it, it will trigger a state update in the parent component, which in turn will trigger a re-render of the parent component and all its children. This can become problematic if the component tree is large and/or the state changes frequently, as it can cause a lot of unnecessary re-renders.

Another reason is that it can violate the principle of encapsulation, which is one of the key benefits of using React. Encapsulation means that each component should have its own isolated state and behavior, and should not directly modify the state of its parent or sibling components. When a child component receives a state updater function as a prop, it has access to and can modify the state of its parent component, which can make it harder to reason about the behavior of the component tree.

Instead of passing the setAddedPhotos function down to child components. you can pass the behavior function like this.

```
import React from 'react';

function PlacesForm() {
  const [addedPhotos, setAddedPhotos] = useState([]);

  const handleAddedPhotos = (newStates) => {
    setAddedPhotos(prev => [...prev, ...newStates]);
  };

  return (
    <PhotosUploader addedPhotos={addedPhotos} handleAddedPhotos={handleAddedPhotos} />
  );
}

function PhotosUploader({ addedPhotos, handleAddedPhotos }) {
    const uploadPhoto = async (e) => {
        const files = e.target.files
        const data = new FormData()
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            data.append('photos', files[i])
        }
        try {
            const {data:filenames} = await axios.post('/upload', data, {
               headers: {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
            })
            handleAddedPhotos(filenames)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
         }
    }

  return (
       <></>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem is very common for new coder every time i user spread operator in call back function i get this error  **something is not iterable** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlaRv.png)

and the solution is =>
add curly braces in spread operator
[{...prev},url]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).